# sapui5 pass parameter to value help dialog of smartFilterBar ControlConfiguration

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have SmartFilterBar on my page based on oData service. One of filterable fields has value help dialog. When value help dialog opened i need to fill one of search parameters in this value help dialog. How can i do this? I can't get value help dialog by control because "byId() method" i don't now id of created dialog.

Comment: If you use the the smartfilter (based on the annotations), it should work right out of the box, so no intervention is needed from your side to hand the value over to the field. Something is wrong with annotations, perhaps.

Comment: Yes now it is working right out of the box correctly. But i need to fill one of search parameter automatically in opened dialog box. Like in screenshot: https://prnt.sc/h3ek1m

Comment: @ИльдарМурзенков I understood you issue, if it was the SmartField in a Form it would be easy to prefill the VH dialog via annotations but I don't know how to do that in the FilterBar. Probably there shouls be an annotation, which is not known for me, you have to find it. Other "hack" soluction would be to get this dialog by id - to do that you need to inspect the HTML genereted by ui5 and grab the Id out of there.

Comment: @Andrii Naumovych Thank you for reply. I have already tried "hack" with generated id of HTML element. It is working in devepopent system, but in another system dialog control has different "id", that's why this hack is not applicable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: how can I get id of opened valuehelpdialog:
In the event "onValueHelpRequest" of I redigine "onAfterRendering" method of class "sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog" and in this method I can get the id of the dialog:

```
filterInitialize: function() {
    var oDogovorControl = this.getView().byId("smartFilterBar").getControlByKey("Dogovor");
    oDogovorControl.attachValueHelpRequest(this.onValueHelpRequest, this);
},
onValueHelpRequest: function() {
    sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog.prototype.test = sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog.prototype.onAfterRendering;
    var fntest2 = function(oEvent){
                      this.test();
                      console.log(this.getId());
                    };
    sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog.prototype.onAfterRendering = fntest2;
}
```