# Add default filter value in smart filter bar

Tags: sapui5

My Custom app got `Smart filterbar` which holds the Companycode and Customer number input. We need to pass the CompanyCode value into Customer number `valuehelp` dialog.

When the user click the Customer number Value help dialog, we got three parameter i.e Custmerid, CustName and comp.code in Select from List Tab. We need to pass the CompanyCode value into comp.code.

I have achieved the solution using below link.

[sapui5 pass parameter to value help dialog of smartFilterBar ControlConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46995384/sapui5-pass-parameter-to-value-help-dialog-of-smartfilterbar-controlconfiguratio)

As you now guys, when you open the value help dialog, we got two tabs

1. Select From List and
2. Define Condition

Strange error showing when I click the "DEFINE CONDITION" TAB that

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
>       at f.g.onmousedown (eval at evalModuleStr (jquery.sap.global-dbg.js:3487), :1503:708)
>       at f.a._handleEvent (Element-dbg.js:162)
>       at constructor.U._handleEvent (UIArea-dbg.js:828)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-dbg.js:4737)
>       at HTMLDivElement.c3.handle (jquery-dbg.js:4549)

Please assist me if any one come across the issue.